# what would happen if I use thousands of setTimeouts?

Tags: javascript, node.js, settimeout

a have a site that is server-sided through node.js, it generates a new code each time you refresh the page, I want to detect if 24h has passed since the last code generation, problem is that for me to do I will need to figure out if 24 hours has passed or not if I use setTimeout() on the user's IP there's 2 problems, first problem they can easily change their ip and get a new code or even restart their router and be assigned a new ip as some routers come with dynamic ips, second issue considering that there will be thousands of users coming daily or even hourly to the website with that amount of setTimeouts the server will be overloaded with the amount of memory allocated for setTimeouts alone. I've read how setTimeouts work and they allocate some space in the JavaScript compiler to run at their specified time so my heap or memory will most definitely be overloaded because of it, is there a better way to figure out if 24 hours has passed or not without using setTimeout()?

I tried looking up the same issue and couldn't find anything that solves this problem, I thought of using a database for this but another issue will arise as I will need to loop through the entire database checking if current time is 24 hours higher than the document creation time and a loop like that will either take days to complete and will fail in case if the API goes down (i restart it regularly to update stuff)

I'm trying to find a solution that won't destroy my server with setTimeouts and won't fail if the API goes down for whatever reason and optionally be able to figure out if the user is spoofing ips or not

Comment: offload this functionality to another microservice with a cron job

Comment: store the values into a database with the associtated ip address

Comment: in microservice, just query the database, with the data record by ip, have a "last_updated" column, if 24 have passed, then update the data and set the last_updated to the current server time.

Comment: _"I expect a solution that..."_: not a great turn of phrase if you want help here.

Comment: @Andy sorry for my misuse of words, I'm new here and stackoverflow asked in include what I expect the result to be.

Comment: There is no fool-proof way to do what you want for anonymous users, for the very reasons you outline in your question. You can either tie the codes to a user_id and require them to authenticate, or you can deal with the fact that users can generate multiple codes. Your second problem isn't one: non-ephemeral state should be stored in the **persistence layer**, not in memory on your web server.

Comment: @DeanVanGreunen thank you. I will keep it in mind while setting up the service.